# mod_geoip на Apache2. Настройка перенаправления со всех страниц сайта на одну, через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, geoip

Сервер - Apache 2.4;
Модули - mod_geoip, mod_rewrite.

Установил mod_geoip, настраиваю .htaccess редирект со всех страниц сайта на одну https://example.com/restricted/ для пользователей из КНР и Индии.

Используемое правило htaccess #1

```
RewriteEngine On
GeoIPEnable On
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(CN|IN)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/restricted/$1 [L]
```

В результате граждане КНР и Индии получают ошибку:
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

выглядит примерно так:

```
www.example.com:443 40.108.122.138 - - [29/Jan/2019:21:41:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 3942 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KH$
www.example.com:443 40.108.122.138 - - [29/Jan/2019:21:41:16 +0000] "GET /restricted/ HTTP/1.1" 302 664 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.$
www.example.com:443 40.108.122.138 - - [29/Jan/2019:21:41:16 +0000] "GET /restricted/restricted/ HTTP/1.1" 302 678 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebK$
www.example.com:443 40.108.122.138 - - [29/Jan/2019:21:41:16 +0000] "GET /restricted/restricted/restricted/ HTTP/1.1" 302 692 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Ap$
www.example.com:443 40.108.122.138 - - [29/Jan/2019:21:41:16 +0000] "GET /restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/ HTTP/1.1" 302 706 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; $
www.example.com:443 40.108.122.138 - - [29/Jan/2019:21:41:17 +0000] "GET /restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/ HTTP/1.1" 302 720 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; $
www.example.com:443 40.108.122.138 - - [29/Jan/2019:21:41:17 +0000] "GET /restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/ HTTP/1.1" 302 734 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows N$
www.example.com:443 40.108.122.138 - - [29/Jan/2019:21:41:17 +0000] "GET /restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/ HTTP/1.1" 302 748 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Wi$
www.example.com:443 40.108.122.138 - - [29/Jan/2019:21:41:17 +0000] "GET /restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/restricted/ HTTP/1.1"
```

и т.д.

Правило htaccess #2

```
RewriteEngine On
GeoIPEnable On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} (CN|IN) [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://example.com/restricted/ [R=302,L]
```

В результате граждане КНР и Индии:
переход по example.com -> заветный редирект на https://example.com/restricted/ 
 - работает; 
переход по example.com/about/ -> заветный редирект на https://example.com/restricted/ - не работает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?! Как настроить редирект со всех страниц на одну единственную для пользователей из КНР и Индии?

Примечание:
В htaccess так же присутствует:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Так же в настройках sites-enabled/example.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        ServerAdmin support@example.com
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        ServerAdmin support@example.com
        RewriteEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]` замените на `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/restricted/$ [NC]`

Comment: @de_frag В случае замены `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC] замените на RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/restricted/$ [NC]` в "Правило htaccess #2" - получаю ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.